# Whats a better way to code a command line interface in c++?

Tags: c++, python

I'm using run of the mill C++, and im building a small "Zork-esc" game as a pet project to exercise my newly learned C++ skills. the following code works perfectly, however it will be a  pain to have to do this for every command/argument combo so if anybody out there can save me some trouble then please do :D ...

as it stands i have this function responsible for processing commands at run-time...

```
void execute()
{
    //###### Command builder ######
    cout << ">>>";
    char input[100];
    cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));
    cout << input << endl;
    string newin = input;
    //###### Execution Phase ######
    if(newin=="derp"){
        // normally functions go here
        cout << "You did it :D" << endl;
    }else if(newin=="attack player1 player2"){
        // normally functions go here
        cout << "player1 attacks player2" << endl;
    }else{
        // quriky error message for the user
        cout << "dafuq?" << endl;
    }
    execute();
}
```

it takes your input and compares it to all the possible string combinations and when it finds a match its suppose to run the corresponding functions placed inside the IF staments

like i said it works but there is much room for improvement i feel...

#### EDIT

I'm basically porting a program i made in python, in that language it took three lines and 10 minutes for me to figure it out.

i used the eval() function with some string so i could literally just type in the function name using the standard "name(arg)" format. it basiclly just evaluated my string and ran the function, like this...

```
def execute(arg):
    try:
        eval(arg)
    except TypeError:
        print('=====## Alert ##=========================================================')
        print('You must provide the arguments in the parentheses')
        print('=========================================================================')
    except SyntaxError:
        print('=====## Alert ##=========================================================')
        print('I didn\'t understand that D:')
        print('=========================================================================')
```

so if i had a function called attack() that took two arguments "player1" and "player2"
i could type it in to the prompt "attack(player1, player2)" and it would run that just like if i had typed that exact thing in to that body of the code to run it. So is there a way to have c++ evaluate a string as if it were code? Like...

string derp = "attack(player1, player2)"

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a map (probably `std::unordered_map`) to...map from the inputs to the appropriate actions:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unary_function *> actions;

class attack : public std::unary_function /*... */
class flee : public std::unary_function /* ... */

action["attack"] = attack;
action["flee"] = flee;
// ...
```

Of course, you can get a lot more sophisticated than just using `unary_function` (which really largely obsolete in C++11). That's only intended as a quick sketch of an idea, not anything approaching finished code.

Comment: thanks bro but it might be a bit over my head because in a noob and all... Ill look in to what you have suggested